# Eu tenho esse json em React js! Como faço para pegar esse src de cada um JSON e passar todos eles como varias imagens no React? Tô aprendendo!

Tags: javascript, react

Este é o JSON obtido através do Puppeteer:

```
[
  {
    "src": "https://instagram.ffor9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.280.720.720a/s640x640/243514741_829398887750929_7555907807919756011_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.ffor9-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=ZjOHxgkiE0YAX8jFhig&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=a128ed63ed08b7d792b5e3d6492d0852&oe=61572BA0&_nc_sid=7bff83"
  },
  {
    "src": "https://instagram.ffor9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.280.720.720a/s640x640/243161222_3063170977298797_2390805453276083538_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.ffor9-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=pOUY9OkehocAX__0Wjv&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=6a069b55664a0f3b60e7efecafddde83&oe=6156FD14&_nc_sid=7bff83"
  },]
```

este seria o código React JS:

```
export default function App(){

render(
<div style = {{...}}>
{json.map(src_do_json=><img style = {{...}} src = {src_do_json}></img>)}
</div>
)}
```

Comment: O stack limitou meu codigo do React não sei o por quê

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um map exatamente como você estava fazendo e retornar uma imagem a cada iteração:

```
json.map(src_do_json => (
  <img src={src_do_json.src} />
))
```